# Distinct results from Spring Data JPA Specification by one column

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteriaquery

I have the following table on database:

| id | employee_id | title | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | title1 | 2022-10-10 |
| 1 | 10 | title2 | 2022-10-11 |

I want fetch data by distinct on title column;

**by sql I can do this:**

```
select distinct on (employee_id) *
from contracts
order by employee_id, created_at desc
```

The size of result is one and it is correct:

| id | employee_id | title | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | title2 | 2022-10-11 |

But when I want implement this by `psecification`, cannot `distinct` result by column:

```
Specification { root: Root<Contract>, query: CriteriaQuery<*>, criteriaBuilder: CriteriaBuilder ->
            val firstNamePredicate: Predicate =
                    criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get<String>("employee").get<String>("id"), "1")
            query.distinct(true)
            criteriaBuilder.and(firstNamePredicate)
        }
```

This query return all rows that `employee_id` is equals **1**.

I applied below changes, but result not changed:

`query.select(root.get<String>("employee").get("id")).distinct(true)`

How can I apply distinct on column?

Comment: What makes you think both are the same? Your first attempt is only adding a where clause on `employee_id` not a distinct on a certain column. The second does only a `select  employee_id` with a distinct. So they aren't even remotely the same. However I'm not aware that you can do this with JPA as this seems to be a Postgres feature. To mimic you could write a query that selects the top most employee record for a certain id. As that looks like what you want to achieve.

Comment: hey i have the same problem, did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: @Diego Yes. I will try to explain the solution under this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution in SQL is to use **max** function. In this question, I want to find employee by bigger **created_at** value. I can use follow SQL query:

```
select employee_id, max(created_at)
from contracts
group by employee_id;
```

Following the above answer, I used the below solution on **Specification**:

```
Subquery<Long> sub = q.subquery(Long.class);     
Root<Contract> subRoot = sub.from(Contract.class);     
sub.select(cb.max(subRoot.get("created_at")))
   .where(cb.equal(root.get("employee_id"), subRoot.get("employee_id")));
return cb.equal(root.get("created_at"), sub);
```